# Piping images to FFmpeg stdin

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, pipe

Good morning, I need to stream trough hls many images that come in a folder as if they were video frames. I don't know prior how many they are so I believe I need to keep FFmpeg opened and passing them via stdin. I read this article already 
[create video from growing image sequence](https://superuser.com/questions/1257122/create-video-from-a-growing-image-sequence-using-ffmpeg)
and I changed the c# code to fit my problem like this :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace Example
{
public class Example
{

static void Main()
{

    AsyncMain().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static async Task AsyncMain()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any button to quit.");
    var maintask = RunFFMPEG();
    var readtask = Task.Run(() => Console.Read());
    await Task.WhenAny(maintask, readtask);
}



static async Task RunFFMPEG()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        const int fps = 30;
        const string outfile = "video_seg_%05d.ts";
        const string dir = @"C:\Users\funny\Desktop\in\";
        const string pattern = "{0}.bmp";
        const string path = dir + pattern;
        const string args = "-y -re -f image2pipe -framerate 2 -i - -c:v libx264 -r {0} -s 1920x1200 -b:v 256000 -flags +global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list list.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts {1}";
        const int startNum = 0;
        const int endNum = 100;

   var pinf = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg", string.Format(args, fps, outfile));
        pinf.UseShellExecute = false;
        pinf.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        pinf.WorkingDirectory = dir;         

        Console.WriteLine("Starting ffmpeg...");
        var proc = Process.Start(pinf);
        using (var stream = new BinaryWriter(proc.StandardInput.BaseStream))
        {
            for (var i = startNum; i < endNum; i++)
            {
               var file = string.Format(path, i.ToString("D4"));
                System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => File.Exists(file) && CanReadFile(file));
                Console.WriteLine("Found file: " + file);
                stream.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(file));
            }
        }

 proc.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine("Closed ffmpeg.");
    });
}


    static bool CanReadFile(string file)
    {
        //Needs to be able to read file
        FileStream fs = null;
        try
        {
            fs = File.OpenRead(file);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
                fs.Close();
        }
    }


}
}
```

When I run the script, I get the following screen :

```
Press any button to quit.
Starting ffmpeg...
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

And it stays like this even though I have images in my folder and they keep coming. Anyone can tell me why isn't it processing? (I've tried to run the FFmpeg command alone on a fixed number of images without piping and it works.)

Comment: Is your code finding images? What does it output on the console (if anything)? Please attempt to troubleshoot your code step-by-step, making sure you know that it's doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Well I'm not into C# much, so I assumed code was right, but since it doesn't display'found file' something is wrong before that. Console output is in the question. It's either the for cyle or the binarywriter that are wrong but I don't know where.

Comment: You don't have to use C#, of course any other language would allow you to do the same. But if it's not finding the files you have to check what path or pattern it's looking for, by debugging the code or inserting some more print statements.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem : basically the code couldn't read images because the path input was wrong;I changed the line

```
var file = string.Format(path, i.ToString("D4"));
```

into

```
var file = string.Format(string.Format(path,i), i.ToString("D4"));
```

and it solved the problem.